# how can i strip http https and www. from url in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to strip http https and www. and trailing / from a url held in a mysql database, but am having trouble formulating my query

Here's what I have so far but its not working.  The query doesnt seem to be structured properly:

```
$checkUrl = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(url, "http://", ""), "www.", ""), "https://","") '/', 1) FROM directory_listings WHERE url = '$url'");

if (mysql_num_rows($checkUrl) > 0) {
            //match directory.';
            }
```

Comment: You probably want to use REGEXP to match only the beginning of the string: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: Your query is using " instead of ', maybe that's your problem. Also, in this case you probably want to manipulate the string in PHP instead of using SQL for that purpose.

Comment: Good Call Nate.  I can't get this to work so will process it in PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "http://www.yourwebsite.com";
$find = array("http://", "https://", "ftp://", "www.");
$replace = array("", "", "");

$finalUrl = str_replace($find, $replace, $url);
    echo $finalUrl;
//yourwebsite.com
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation to your code.